# How to display product condition in ajax-cart.js

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have done:

1. added in classes > cart.php at line 510 `p.condition`
2. added in blockcart-json.tpl `"condition":      {$product.condition|intval},`

it works in blockcart.tpl but it is not working in the ajax-cart.tpl. In other words I must refresh the page. But it should work without refresh when adding products to cart.

in ajax-cart.js I call it by this variable "this.condition" but the result is "undefined"

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: maybe you should post your code for better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
|intval
```

It´s a number value. You may use something like that

```
{$product.condition|capitalize|json_encode}
```

Then to add it in the ajax without refresh do the following

-In the blockcart-json.tpl (* div layer_cart *) add this.
example #default-theme:

```
<div class="product-condition" style="margin-top:10px"> <span style="font-weight: bold; color:#333;margin-top:10px"> {l s='Condition: ' mod='blockcart'}</span> <span id="layer_cart_product_condition" class="product-condition"></span></div>
<div>
```

-And, finally in ajax-cart.js (* updateLayer : function(product) *) 
add this

```
$('#layer_cart_product_condition').text(product.condition);
```